# Wind direction from U and V vectors in R

Tags: r, trigonometry

I have a data frame with U and V components of wind per lat/long and time period. I am want to convert U and V to 0/360 degrees with the angle being the direction the wind is blowing. IE angle = 90 so an arrow would point east with the head of the arrow point east.

Is my approach correct?

```
vec <- vec_data %>%
  mutate(angle = (270 - (atan2(u, v) * (180/pi))%%360)) %>%  
  dplyr::select(x, everything()) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c(u,v))
```

sample of data

```
vec_data <- structure(list(x = c(-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, 
-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686), y = c(4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 4127041.55797241, 
4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 
4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 
4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 
4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 
4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 4141341.55797241, 
4141341.55797241), date = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"2", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"), u = c(1.66167736011318, 
6.83296343516835, 3.96181096898258, 0.788026174565747, -0.312470918948628, 
0.300309963467825, 0.916757077990102, 0.310768184297616, -1.29158147995779, 
-1.31376372692617, -1.66191173747863, 2.87384174791852, -2.72346036457012, 
-4.21792509062084, -2.40266457337624, 1.06865369695715, 0.562370768251253, 
-1.41470744080529, -2.50225113360906, -3.08841433565671, -1.99137572090069, 
-1.63160254653287, 6.85358324798006, 8.20036962506425, 11.1683554133792, 
11.7929781583214, 11.6436527553446, 11.4508322940423, 9.35378123305564, 
1.54680197276442, 7.08724684317882, 3.38671731007152, 0.842576387043412, 
-0.0517387871845842, 0.506540543351971, 1.06872794962077, 0.435409178170888, 
-1.26718504490349, -1.40597136646379, -1.69808305965404, 2.20426699838015, 
-2.6652570101434, -4.07755093140757, -2.23149363058989, 1.15367189073885, 
0.462546873682681, -1.4968921427486, -2.73315063764403, -3.42767860856885, 
-2.3603575894985), v = c(5.1614914384995, -3.93996789092725, 
-4.77348344959728, -6.50933351032295, -5.5211293616109, -5.37474453654282, 
-7.10083929605741, -7.84623830632686, -8.47344401958608, -7.42520870238044, 
-7.02041948151032, 6.15203571589491, -6.28357927515228, -4.77416649319221, 
-4.894505876523, -6.25522001189335, -7.81645871536792, -7.03446690968903, 
-5.47509452445269, -4.31998499082152, -4.06746762207179, -3.76746304731775, 
8.32609316223089, 11.1671580904602, -1.16157978077442, 0.21804143150561, 
0.368133050752144, 0.530471045407084, -3.73607256972132, 5.41266702140862, 
-3.72311988832072, -5.23230479719324, -6.49302562083498, -5.42526764553153, 
-5.32821922583625, -7.06827999658731, -7.80898770777897, -8.45703447165568, 
-7.32175587369518, -6.77699499074815, 6.5662669335256, -5.98919286659384, 
-4.46358327686848, -4.54938658557657, -6.14705439888149, -7.73669518817978, 
-6.85657212798357, -5.05679807302411, -3.83526543321167, -3.73671395318424
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), groups = structure(list(x = c(-13579553.7112686, -13579553.7112686
), y = c(4127041.55797241, 4141341.55797241), .rows = structure(list(
    1:29, 30:50), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: You re sharing vec, no vec_data. i.e. the transformed variables , not the originals.

Comment: @RicVillalba my mistake. Just updated with correct data